# probing/setting Xorg conf values

Tags: xorg, screen-tearing

Is there any way to probe values from Xorg just so i don't have to restart it several times, each time with each value to see which one works best. By probing i can already write down the behaviour for one value...

for example, i'm trying to get rid of video tearing on my HD4000 GPU. `man intel` shows several interesting values, such as `option "CacheLines"` and `option "AccelMethod"` and `option "TripeBuffer"` etc. I want to try several of them, but i am surelly already running with one value of the few possible... but since i don't know which one, i'd have to set one, restart X, write down results, repeat.

going further on that... any way to play with those options faster? either a soft reset kind of thing or who knows, some real time changes?

Thank you,